# Match whole sentence with ÅÄÖ characters with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to match a sentence with `preg_match` but I can't get it working be cause of the Swedish characters Å, Ä, and Ö. The sentence is "Filmen är försedd med svensk text" and this is what I've tried: `preg_match('/Filmen är försedd med svensk text./i', $information['summary'])` but when I trying to match it, it wont print out anything! If I keep "svensk text" it works perfectly.

Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file?

Comment: If your string internally is stored as multibyte (lets say that you output stuff in utf-8) this won't match.

Comment: @Nobody: `charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: And what is the default charset of php (written in php.ini)? If they do not match, your strings will be different.

Comment: is that the output from the response headers, or the actual encoding of the file? If you output just $information['summary'], does the åäö show correctly?

Comment: @jishi: The string was `Filmen Ã¤r fÃ¶rsedd med svensk text.` in `$information['summary']`. Many thanks! The problem has now been solved.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Use [this calculator](http://ascii-table.com/calculator.php) to find the hexadecimal representation of the desirable characters.
2.- Use these hexadecimal representations instead of the Swedish characters (Å, Ä, and Ö).

Example: Å = \xc5